# Pass object in all methods of all controllers in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this code in the HomeController@index:

```
$towns = Town::all();
return Redirect::to('home')
                ->with('towns', $towns);
```

Is there any way I can tell Laravel to execute that lines of code before the end of methods and controllers I define without me copying and pasting those lines of code in every method?

Comment: Create a new method (function) put all code you want to be executed and just call the method in the end of the method. Another way is to create ["after" middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#defining-middleware) that handles this for you.

Comment: reading about "after" middleware now... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that, you can just share this data with all views by using the [`view()->share()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) method in a service provider:

```
view()->share('towns', Town::all());
```

You can also use [a view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers) for that:

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $view->with('towns', Town::all());
}
```

Comment: can you explain in more detail or maybe a URL? Thanks

Comment: @Poxxac I've updated the answer with another solution and URLs. Please check.

Comment: I would avoid `->share()` I feel like its hidden (in one of many service providers) on another hand view composer is a valid technique thats obvious from folder/file structure.

Answer (score -1):

You can extend all controllers from your basic controller. Use Controller.php on app/Http/Controllers/controller.php or create new one.

Add myThreeLines to base controller.

controller.php:

```
function myThreeLines(){
    $towns = Town::all();
    return Redirect::to('home')
            ->with('towns', $towns);
}

class TestController extend Controller{

    function index(){

        return $this->myThreeLines();

    }
}
```

Comment: This may not work because not all the methods goes to the same redirect. Thanks tho